# Accessing functions from different scripts in unity C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to unity and I'm trying to make collectibles in a game but i need to keep a tally of how many items have been collected but still have the collected item disappear. So far I have this. And yes the collectables are hairspray :p

**Collection.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Collection : MonoBehaviour {

public control controlSrc;


void OnTriggerEnter () {
    controlSrc.AddScore();
    killHairSpray();
}


void killHairSpray () {
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

}
```

**control.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class control : MonoBehaviour {

public int hcTot = 0;

public void AddScore () {
hcTot = hcTot + 1;
Debug.Log("Working");
}
}
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working but the console says;

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Collection.OnTriggerEnter () (at Assets/Collection.cs:10)

Thanks:) this has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely haven't connected anything to the controlSrc variable so it's empty. Hence the null reference exception.

In the Unity editor select the GameObject with the Collection.cs script, then in the Inspector set the controlSrc (most likely listed as "Control Src") by assigning the game object containing the control.cs script.